# Android Error parsing XML: not well-formed

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an error: Error parsing XML:not well-formed(invaled token) in my activity_main.xml file and I can't figure out for the life of me what it is. I have tried retyping it to ensure it's nothing to do with the quotation marks. I'm pretty much copying across code from a book.
The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0ak81Gwf6w8ZZhWxdNiCS8e6LvqrrwZ8nUZKmbQ" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0ak81Gwf6w8ZZhWxdNiCS8e6LvqrrwZ8nUZKmbQ" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You did not close the LinearLayout starting-tag.

Comment: Save it and clean the project